# How to animate an image within a boundary in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate an image using jQuery within a rectangular boundary but my code doesn't restrict how far the image can move. How can I modify my code to restrict the image to move only within a 200px by 300px box?

index.html

```
  <img class="pic" src="panda.jpg"/>
```

style.css

```
  .pic {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: 355px; 
        margin-top: -180px;
      }
```

jQuery

```
  $(document).keydown(function(key) {
  switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
  case 37:
  $('.pic').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
  break;
  case 38:
  $('.pic').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
  break;
  case 39:
  $('.pic').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
  break;
  case 40:
  $('.pic').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
  break;
    }
 });
```

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/waAK2/

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your own boundaries and limitations.

EDIT

notice I use margn-left and margin-top here. Make sure to set width and height of the holder and .pic in your css. Made the movementSpeed editable.

```
var movementSpeed = 10;

var leftMarginLimit = parseInt($('.pic').parent().css('width')) - parseInt($('.pic').css('width'));
var topMarginLimit = parseInt($('.pic').parent().css('height')) - parseInt($('.pic').css('height'));

var leftMargin = parseInt($('.pic').css('margin-left'));
var topMargin = parseInt($('.pic').css('margin-top'));

$(document).keydown(function(key) {

    // LEFT
    if (key.which == 37)
    {
        leftMargin -=movementSpeed;
        if (leftMargin < 0){leftMargin = 0;}
        if (leftMargin > leftMarginLimit){leftMargin = leftMarginLimit;}
        $('.pic').animate({'margin-left': leftMargin+'px'}, 'fast');
    }

    // RIGHT
    if (key.which == 39)
    {
        leftMargin +=movementSpeed;
        if (leftMargin < 0){leftMargin = 0;}
        if (leftMargin > leftMarginLimit){leftMargin = leftMarginLimit;}
        $('.pic').animate({'margin-left': leftMargin+'px'}, 'fast');
    }

    // UP
    if (key.which == 38)
    {
        topMargin -=movementSpeed;
        if (topMargin < 0){topMargin = 0;}
        if (topMargin > topMarginLimit){topMargin = topMarginLimit;}
        $('.pic').animate({'margin-top': topMargin+'px'}, 'fast');
    }

    // DOWN
    if (key.which == 40)
    {
        topMargin +=movementSpeed;
        if (topMargin < 0){topMargin = 0;}
        if (topMargin > topMarginLimit){topMargin = topMarginLimit;}
        $('.pic').animate({'margin-top': topMargin+'px'}, 'fast');
    }
});
```

Instead of the animation you should try

```
$('.pic').css({'margin-left': leftMargin+'px'});
```

it feels more responsive, else you have to wait for the animation to finish and so on.

Comment: Using your code, When my image reaches the limit, I am no longer able to move the image in any direction at all. I want to still be able to move the image around. For example, if I reach my left limit, I still want to be able to move the image to the right, up or down. I just don't want it to pass the boundary. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: yeah, you have to do the counter up when pressing left and counter down when pressing right counter = counter - 10; This you have to do before running the if statement. Let me know if you dont understand.

Comment: Is possible if you can demo this on jsfiddle? It will be easier for me to see what you mean when I see it in action. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

Hey just made a fiddle for your box with checks for all corners... just need to put in some conditions to make it stop.

Something along these lines:

```
if ($('.pic').css("left") >= "10") {
    $('.pic').animate({
        left: "-=10px"
        }, 'fast');
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/descene/waAK2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Put a container with position as relative. Any animation of the child elements (position with absolute) within that element will be stay inside, And you could check the element boundary inside **step function** to prevent it from moving outside the boundary.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GyvT/) will print properties during in each animation. You can check and handle any logic inside it.

```
$('#child-1').animate({
    left: 10,
    top: 100
}, {
    duration: 3000,
    step: function(now, fx){
        console.log(now, fx);
    }
})
```